# WPF - OxyPlot - Binding to DataPoints

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I am working on a WPF app that uses [OxyPlot](https://github.com/oxyplot/documentation-examples/blob/master/HelloWorld/WpfApplication2/MainViewModel.cs).

I've followed the example. I am successfully plotting a chart using the following XAML:

```
<oxy:Plot Height="640" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ResultSet1}" />
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ResultSet2}" />
    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ResultSet3}" />
  </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public IList<DataPoint> ResultSet1 { get; set; }

  public IList<DataPoint> ResultSet2 { get; set; }

  public IList<DataPoint> ResultSet3 { get; set; }

  public void Load()
  {
    this.ResultSet1 = new List<DataPoint>
    {
      new DataPoint(0, 4),
      new DataPoint(40, 12),
      new DataPoint(50, 12)
    };

    this.ResultSet2 = new List<DataPoint>
    {
      new DataPoint(-0.4, 3),
      new DataPoint(8, 12),
      new DataPoint(48, 11)
    };

    this.ResultSet3 = new List<DataPoint>
    {
      new DataPoint(2, 5),
      new DataPoint(12, 14),
      new DataPoint(52, 13)
    };
  }

  public void Refresh()
  {
    this.ResultSet1 = new List<DataPoint>();
    this.ResultSet2 = new List<DataPoint>();
    this.ResultSet3 = new List<DataPoint>();
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("should be empty");
  }
}
```

In my code, I have a "Refresh" button. When a user clicks that, I'm trying to refresh the data that's displayed. However, its like the results are not getting updated in the UI. I added the `MessageBox` shown above, to ensure that i was actually getting into the `Refresh` method. That message box appears. So, at this point, I know:

a) The OxyPlot chart is working because my initial result set values that are hard-coded are appearing fine.
b) I've successfully wired-up the view model.
c) I'm getting into the `Refresh` method.

I'm just not sure why the points on the chart do not seem to be refreshing. Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your view model; Otherwise, the bound target `ItemsSource` in view still listen to the change in the old objects and wouldn't know the property is replaced (pointing to a new object after Refresh).

Comment: :). One of these days, I will remember `INotifyPropertyChanged`. For some reason, I always forget. Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: @Peter, I think you should write the answer to question ;)

Comment: I always create a PlotModel property in die ViewModel and bind them to the xaml an then call PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true) on this property. This will render the plot with the new data or in your case it will show no data because the lists are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `IList` use `ObservableCollection`

```
 public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> ResultSet1 { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> ResultSet2 { get; set; }
 public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> ResultSet3 { get; set; }
```

and instead of using `new IList<T>()` use

```
ResultSet1.Clear();
ResultSet2.Clear();
ResultSet3.Clear();
```